# using 'off' or 'from' in a sentence

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, sentence

I am not a native english speaker and was wondering in the following sentence if the word **off** or **from** is used see below what i think is correct.

Jumping off the ship on the right time.

or

Jumping from the ship on the right time.

It is in the context of someone leaving a company when it gets rough. It is in a friendly context if that makes any difference.

Comment: Should be "**at** the right time".

Comment: In addition to Hot Licks' correct suggestion, I think you may have the wrong idiom.  There is an metaphorical idiom:  'to jump ship', which means to get off or abandon a ship (before it hits the rocks).  So 'jumping ship at the right time' would be the colloquial expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The joys of prepositions!

You may jump *from* a ship, *from* a train, *from* a step, *from* a height. You jumped in a direction whose starting point is defined by "*from*".

You may also jump *off* them. You were *on*; after you jump you are *off*.

You may do something "*at* the right time": it is done when the time is right. "*at*" refers to a particular time (e.g. at ten o'clock, at the beginning of the year, at the dawn of time, at the time I married etc).

You do not do something *on* the right time even though the expression is confusingly close to expressions such as "The train arrived *on* time", "the plane left *on* time", both of which tell you that the time was the same as that predicted "*on*" a timetable.

So "you jumped off the ship at the right time" is the correct conventional version.

Answer (score 0):

Both off and from make sense, but honestly it doesn't sound like native language. We have shortened this expression to "jumping ship" as in "I can't believe you would jump ship right when we are about to hit the big time!"

Also, "on the right time" is inaccurate, "at the right time" is more natural. So "She was interested in jumping ship at the right time" is how I would revise that sentence.